# Find sub areas of a function in a circle

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, circles, area

I have a cellular signal calculation function, which calculates the signal given the distance from the antenna. Without the constants, the function is basically: $f(d)=1/(d^α)$ where α is a parameter.

I also have another function, which calculates the signal given the distance from another antenna. Without the constants, the function is basically: $g(d)=1/(d^β)$ where β is a parameter.

The final gain is basically $T(d)=min(1/(d^α),1/(k^\beta))$

I attach an example: 
[image]

Now I'm lokking on floor(T).
So each point has a value, and since I look at the floor of the function, I have areas with the same value.

As in this example:
[image]

Is there a way to calculate the area of a certain value? For example, what is the area of points with value equal to 5.

Comment: May I ask: why do you choose the minimum of the two?

Comment: Since I need to link with both of them. So the gain is the minimum of them.